# How to solve compare two datatables linq to sql error?

Tags: linq

I have two datatables and I need to compare one columns and delete some results .(One Columns=ID)

I use datatable 1 and datatable 2 linq expression.I want to database3.

Common area ise ID:83,21

```
datatable 1

StudentID     ClassNumber     No     
83                65           1        
21                28           15       
35                56           87

datatable 2

StudentID      BranchNumber

83                  3

21                  2

datatable 3

StudentID      ClassNumber

83                 65

21                 28
```

I write this query

```
public static DataTable Student(Datatable ds,Datatable dc)
{
   DataTable StudentDatabaseID1= new DataTable();
   DataTable StudentDatabaseID2= new DataTable();

 var result=from a in StudentDatabaseID1.AsEnumerable()
            join b in StudentDatabaseID2.AsEnumerable()
            on a.Field<int>("StudentID") equals b.Field<int>("StudentID")
            select 
            {
            StudentID=a.Field<int>("StudentID"),
            ClassNumber=a.Field<int>("ClassNumber"),
            }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you haven't data in `StudentDatabaseID1` and `StudentDatabaseID2` because they are new variables, maybe you have to use `Datatable ds,Datatable dc` ???, check it, code works fine like next example:

**CODE (this is for LinqPad but you can re-use in your code):**

```
void Main()
{ 
    //  Build data

    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable(); 
    dt1.Clear();
    dt1.Columns.Add("StudentId", typeof(Int32));
    dt1.Columns.Add("ClassNumber", typeof(Int32));
    dt1.Columns.Add("No", typeof(Int32));

    DataRow row1 = dt1.NewRow();
    row1["StudentId"] = 83;
    row1["ClassNumber"] = 65;
    row1["No"] = 1;
    dt1.Rows.Add(row1);

    row1 = dt1.NewRow();
    row1["StudentId"] = 21;
    row1["ClassNumber"] = 28;
    row1["No"] = 15;
    dt1.Rows.Add(row1);

    row1 = dt1.NewRow();
    row1["StudentId"] = 35;
    row1["ClassNumber"] = 56;
    row1["No"] = 87;
    dt1.Rows.Add(row1);

    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable(); 
    dt2.Clear();
    dt2.Columns.Add("StudentId", typeof(Int32));
    dt2.Columns.Add("BranchNumber", typeof(Int32));

    DataRow row2 = dt2.NewRow();
    row2["StudentId"] = 83;
    row2["BranchNumber"] = 3;
    dt2.Rows.Add(row2);

    row2 = dt2.NewRow();
    row2["StudentId"] = 21;
    row2["BranchNumber"] = 2;
    dt2.Rows.Add(row2);

    //  Do query
    var result = 
        from a in dt1.AsEnumerable()
        join b in dt2.AsEnumerable() on a.Field<int>("StudentID") equals b.Field<int>("StudentID")
        select new {
            StudentID=a.Field<int>("StudentID"),
            ClassNumber=a.Field<int>("ClassNumber"),
        };

    // Print result     
    result.Dump();  
}
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: Hi.In fact, I have my paintings and I will take the full tables.I can't add it by saying add because there is a lot of data.How do I get data from that field in the table?.This datatable 1 and datatable 2 contain too many students.So dt1.add How do I get the table from the table.Because I can't do this when there is too much data count.

Comment: @K.E Code modified, check it and tell me :P

Comment: hi.I has many rows my database and many value compare.How to many value add row. For example; 1000 rows compare and same 500 rows.How to solve problem?

Comment: @K.E Please, explain a bit more and clear, I can't understand you :P